# Convert excel workbook to byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, excel

I have an ["excel library"](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) workbook and want to convert it to a byte[] so I could return the data with the [File method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx) exist in asp.net mvc controller.
There are "Save" and "SaveToStream" method, but no convert to byte[].

How can I return the excel file without saving it in server before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a SaveToStream you could pass in a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) into that method. Then, once all the bytes are written call [ToArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) on the memory stream, which should give you a byte array.

Comment: Could you provide some code here? I tried but the Excel file is broken.

Comment: If I have a *SaveToStream*?  Checked my desk drawer, didn't find it there.  If you have another sentence maybe this might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to convert it to a byte[]? File can also return a stream.

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Worksheet worksheet = new Worksheet("First Sheet");
worksheet.Cells[0, 1] = new Cell(9999999);

workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheet);

MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
workbook.SaveToStream(m);

return File(m, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work because the memorty stream isn't in the beginning. so I wrote ToArray().