# Convert Excel into Memory Stream and download via AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, excel, memorystream

I want to create a Excel file dynamically in C# and I need to make it as downloadable in AngularJS HTML Button Click.

I referred the following link to create Excel dynamically http://www.increvcorp.com/manipulating-excel-spreadsheet-using-c/

It's working fine. But it saves the file in local storage

```
 xlWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\\Mobile_List.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

I referred one more post, they given idea to **convert directly from workbook to Memory Stream** - [Convert excel workbook to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201774/convert-excel-workbook-to-byte).

But, in that post they used the

```
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
workbook.SaveToStream(m);
```

I Can't able to find the method `SaveToStream` in my workbook, it shows an error

> 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook' does not contain a
>   definition for 'SaveToStream' and no extension method 'SaveToStream'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How could I make it as memory stream and send it back to AngularJS for download by clicking the HTML Button ?

I referred one more post to [AngularJS $http-post - convert binary to excel file and download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447952/angularjs-http-post-convert-binary-to-excel-file-and-download) - it purely explained the angularJS part and PHP. There is no explanation for C#, that's the main reason I'm posting this question.

Kindly assist me...

Note: Don't convert it from local storage...

Answer (score 0):

If your workbook object does cannot be converted to a byte array, you can still work with the file you saved on your disk :

```
var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("PathToSavedWorkBook");
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    //Use your memorystream
}
```

If you only want a byteArray though, the first line is enough

**EDIT:**

As per the documentation of the class you are using : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.aspx

It seems that it is not possible to not save the workbook in a file

Comment: You could try and save the workbook with [Workbook.SaveCopyAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.savecopyas.aspx) in a temporary folder with a timestamp attached to its filename and then read it in again with the method @Sidewinder94 proposed.